# .exe crashes when I enter a vaue for &records[*rCount].source

Tags: c, while-loop, crash, do-while

Update ***

I have now tried to return something from the function and still the .exe crashes! I am quite new to c so sorry if I am been a bit thick at not spotting why.

```
struct packet* addRecord(int *rCount, struct packet *records){
int valid = 0;  //used to indicated valid input
int length = 0; //used to store the string lengths
int i = 0;    //used in the for loops
char dataTest[51];     //temporary storage of input to be checked before adding to records




do{
    puts("What is the source of this packet?: ");
    if(scanf(" %c", &records[*rCount].source) == 1){  //if correct insert the record at the index
        valid=1;                                //determined by rCount(the current record count passed to addRecord
    }
    else{
        valid = 0;
        getchar();
        puts("\nNot a valid input");
    }

}while(valid!=1);

do{
    puts("What is the destination of this packet?: ");
    if(scanf(" %c", &records[*rCount].destination) == 1)
    {
        valid = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        valid = 1;
        getchar();
        puts("\nNot a valid input");
    }
   }
   while(valid!=1);
   records = realloc(records,(*rCount+1)*sizeof(struct packet));
   return records;
```

}

So I have got this code to work, but when I enter a value for &records[*rCount].source, the .exe crashes. I have been looking at this code for an hour now and cannot find the broken link, but I feel like it's something simple.

Here is the little bit of code that I feel like is not working properly.

Also can someone please explain what == 1 means in the if statement, I've kinda just hacked this code together. Thanks

```
do{
        puts("What is the source of this packet?: ");
        if(scanf("%i", &records[*rCount].source) == 1){  //if correct insert the record at the index
            valid=1;                                //determined by rCount(the current record count passed to addRecord
        }
        else{
            valid = 0;
            getchar();
            puts("\nNot a valid input");
        }

    }while(valid!=1);
```

Full code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

struct packet{ // declare structure for packet creation
        int source;
        int destination;
        int type;
        int port;
        char data[51];
    };

//function prototypes
void listRecords(int, struct packet*);
struct packet* addRecord(int*, struct packet*);
void save(int, struct packet*);
struct packet* open(int*, struct packet*);

int main ()
{
    int recordCount = 0;
    char choice;
    struct packet *records;
    struct packet *temp;

    do {
                printf("\nWhat would you like to do?\n");

                printf("\t1) Add a packet.\n");                 //---------------------//
                printf("\t2) List all packets.\n");             //---------------------//
                printf("\t3) Save packets.\n");                 //---------MENU--------//
                printf("\t4) Clear all packets.\n");            //---------------------//
                printf("\t5) Quit the programme.\n");           //---------------------//

                scanf("%i", &choice); // scan user input and put the entry into variable "choice"
                if(choice == '/n')
                    scanf("%i", &choice);



                switch(choice)
                {
                    case 1: system("cls");
                            records = addRecord(&recordCount, records);
                            break;
                    case 2: system("cls");
                            break;
                    case 3: system("cls");
                            break;
                    case 4: system("cls");
                            break;
                    default: system("cls");
                             printf("%i was not a valid option\n", choice);
                             break;
                }

            }
    while (choice != 5);
    return 0;
}

struct packet* addRecord(int *rCount, struct packet *records){
    int valid = 0;  //used to indicated valid input
    int length = 0; //used to store the string lengths
    int i = 0;    //used in the for loops
    char dataTest[51];     //temporary storage of input to be checked before adding to records




    do{
        puts("What is the source of this packet?: ");
        if(scanf("%i", &records[*rCount].source) == 1){  //if correct insert the record at the index
            valid=1;                                //determined by rCount(the current record count passed to addRecord
        }
        else{
            valid = 0;
            getchar();
            puts("\nNot a valid input");
        }

    }while(valid!=1);

    do{
        puts("What is the destination of this packet?: ");
        if(scanf("%i", &records[*rCount].destination == 1))
        {
            valid = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            valid = 1;
            getchar();
            puts("\nNot a valid input");
        }
       }
       while(valid!=1);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> struct packet *records;
> ```

All well and good but you never actually created a `struct packet` for this pointer to point to. Therefore all access through this pointer is to invalid memory that does not belong to you.

I don't see any need for a pointer here. Simply declare it as:

```
struct packet records;
```

Then *pass* a pointer to that object:

```
case 1: system("cls");
    addRecord(&recordCount, &records);
```

Notice that I've gotten rid of the return for `addRecord`; you simply do not need it. Make it return `void`. As it is now, you are taking one invalid pointer and overwriting it with *another* invalid pointer populated with randomness, since you never *actually* `return` anything. It's the same problem, just happening to trigger a crash due to the random value you get.

Comment: so putting
return records: 
at the end of the function should clear this.
Thanks

Comment: Thank you so much, this has just made it all work!
Thank god for that! :)

Comment: still needed *records or the code became invalid for some reason, unless there is a work around for this, again thank you!

Comment: No, in fact you shouldn't return anything. You're already passing the structure in by pointer; no need to return it back in, too. And you _do_ need to declare the actual structure, not just a pointer. "the code became invalid for some reason" is not a clear description of what problem you faced, but at the moment, until you do as I said in my answer, you still have a memory corruption problem which you may not be aware of.

Comment: Ahhh, sorry I am really new to this and trying to explain the problems I face are pretty difficult. I have done what you said and now everything seems to be working well. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
 if(scanf("%i", &records[*rCount].destination == 1))
```

to

```
 if(scanf("%d", &records[*rCount].destination) == 1)
```

Also change `%i` to `%d` and `char choice;` to `int choice;`
Another problem is you are returning nothing from your function which has pointer to `struct packet` return type .

After some changes that I made the compiling code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

struct packet{ // declare structure for packet creation
        int source;
        int destination;
        int type;
        int port;
        char data[51];
    };

//function prototypes
void listRecords(int, struct packet*);
void addRecord(int*, struct packet*);
void save(int, struct packet*);
struct packet* open(int*, struct packet*);

int main (void)
{
    int recordCount = 0;
    int choice;
    struct packet *records;
    //struct packet *temp;

    do {
                printf("\nWhat would you like to do?\n");

                printf("\t1) Add a packet.\n");                 //---------------------//
                printf("\t2) List all packets.\n");             //---------------------//
                printf("\t3) Save packets.\n");                 //---------MENU--------//
                printf("\t4) Clear all packets.\n");            //---------------------//
                printf("\t5) Quit the programme.\n");           //---------------------//

                scanf("%d", &choice); // scan user input and put the entry into variable "choice"
                if(choice == '\n')
                    scanf("%d", &choice);



                switch(choice)
                {
                    case 1: system("cls");
                             addRecord(&recordCount, records);
                             break;
                    case 2: system("cls");
                             break;
                    case 3: system("cls");
                             break;
                    case 4: system("cls");
                             break;
                    default: system("cls");
                             printf("%d was not a valid option\n", choice);
                             break;
                }

            }
    while (choice != 5);
    return 0;
}

void addRecord(int *rCount, struct packet *records){
    int valid = 0;  //used to indicated valid input
    //int length = 0; //used to store the string lengths
    //int i = 0;    //used in the for loops
    //char dataTest[51];     //temporary storage of input to be checked before adding to records




    do{
        puts("What is the source of this packet?: ");
        if(scanf("%d", &records[*rCount].source) == 1){  //if correct insert the record at the index
            valid=1;                                //determined by rCount(the current     record count passed to addRecord
        }
        else{
            valid = 0;
            getchar();
            puts("\nNot a valid input");
        }

    }while(valid!=1);

    do{
        puts("What is the destination of this packet?: ");
        if(scanf("%d", &records[*rCount].destination) == 1)
        {
            valid = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            valid = 1;
            getchar();
            puts("\nNot a valid input");
        }
    }
       while(valid!=1);
}
```

Comment: this is still crashing although that may help me at a later date, thanks!

Comment: would changing the %i to %c also mean that I would ahve to change the data type for the destination type in the structure?

Comment: No. This change is only for `char` type. No need to change destination type. I edited my answer. There was some typo. Fixed now. This time it will work fine.

Comment: Just update the main post, have I do what what you said was missing/needed editing. Thanks

Comment: Updated my answer. See it again. Now it is working for me without any crash.

Comment: changed choice and the %i to %d, still having a problem....
It's soon as I enter a value for the input for &records[*rCount].source, the programme just pumps out an error and then stop.
Thanks again for the help.

Comment: what did you also return to stop the crash? 
Thanks

Comment: I have posted the full code. It is working for option/choice `1` only (as it should).

Comment: Hi can I ask what OS you are using, as I have just copied and pasted your code into my compiler and it still crashes, wondering if it's the OS. I currently use W7. Thanks for the help still.

Comment: I am using same. WIN7 32-bit. Compiled it with GCC 4.8.1.

Comment: Could it be something to do with mine been 64bit? As I'm really struggling to get the code working. Thanks

Comment: No. Most probably it should not. Which compiler are you using?

Comment: I honestly would not know, it's gcc and thats all I know. it came with codeblocks when I downloaded it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

What is **%i** supposed to be doing? Are you looking for an integer? If so, you want **%d** (*d* for decimal).

**== 1** checks that scanf successfully processed 1 item.

And what @haccks said about missing ).

Comment: i is supposed to be an integer yes, it is trying to get the integer from user input and store it into the "source" part of the structure.